# Update updated_at field when foreign keys change

Tags: django

I have a model called `Questionnaire`. I also have a `Question` model which has a `foreign_key` to `Questionnaire`.

When a `Question` instance that belongs to a `Questionnaire` instance (via `foreign_key`) is UPDATED, I need to update the `updated_at` field on `Questionnaire` too.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this after updating your Question instance:

```
questionnaire = question.questionnaire
questionnaire.updated_at = timezone.now()
questionnaire.save()
```